# Python: Rotation of image and patch

Tags: python, image, rotation, patch

I have been (unsuccesful) in rotating a patch (a ROI) and the corresponding image.

From my understanding, I can see that the ROI/patch rotates correctly if I am centering the object in the center perfectly and with the transform, it rotates the ROI correctly: [Object In center and correct ROI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwlWl.png)

However, if I move the object away from having its center in the center of the image, the transformed patch does not overlay correctly anymore: [Offcentered Object, incorrect ROI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6T72Q.png)

The code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib as mpl

def rotate_image(image, angle):
  image_center = tuple(np.array(image.shape[1::-1]) / 2)
  rot_mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(image_center, angle, 1.0)
  result = cv2.warpAffine(image, rot_mat, image.shape[1::-1], flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
  return result

def crop_image(Message, image):
    coordinates = cv2.selectROI(Message, image)

    if coordinates != []:
        print("\n Succes! ROI has been selected.")
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    r1, c1 = int((coordinates[1])), int((coordinates[0]))  # Upper left corner
    # Lower right corner
    r2, c2 = (int(coordinates[1]+coordinates[3])
              ), (int(coordinates[0]+coordinates[2]))
    r1, c1 = int(r1), int(c1)
    r2, c2 = int(r2), int(c2)
    Matrix = [[r1, c1], [r2, c2]]
    cropped_img = image[(r1): (r2), (c1): (c2)]
    return cropped_img, Matrix

plt.close("all")

h = 500
w=1000
cx = int(w/2)
cy = int(h/2)
rot_angle = -45
W_Rec = 300
H_Rec = 100
upper_left_point = (cx-int(W_Rec/2),cy-int(H_Rec/2))
lower_right_point = (cx+int(W_Rec/2),cy+int(H_Rec/2))
img = np.ones((h,w), dtype=np.uint8)
rec_cv2=cv2.rectangle(img, pt1=upper_left_point, pt2=lower_right_point, color=255, thickness=-1)

fig,axs=plt.subplots(ncols=3,tight_layout=True)
axs[0].imshow(img)
axs[0].set_title("Original")

im_rot = rotate_image(img,rot_angle)
axs[1].imshow(im_rot)

_,Matrix = crop_image("Define Matrix",im_rot)

c0,c1 = Matrix[0][1], Matrix[1][1]
r0,r1 = Matrix[0][0], Matrix[1][0]
roi = np.asarray([[r0,c0],[r1,c1]])

rec = plt.Rectangle((c0,r0),(c1-c0),(r1-r0),fill=False,color="w",ls="dashed")
axs[1].add_patch(rec)
axs[1].set_title("Rotated with patch")

axs[2].imshow(img)

tr = mpl.transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg_around(cx,cy,-rot_angle)
ts = axs[2].transData

rec_rot = plt.Rectangle((c0,r0),(c1-c0),(r1-r0),fill=False,color="w",ls="dashed",transform=tr+ts)
axs[2].add_patch(rec_rot)
axs[2].set_title("Original w/ rotated patch")

for n in range(3):
    axs[n].axis("off")
plt.show()
```

I have only gotten the understanding of that it rotates with respect to the ax.transData, but not sure what it represents.

The rotation (tr) seems correct, however it is the translation that goes wrong if the object is not centered...

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're facing arises due to a discrepancy between the centre of rotation of the image and the ROI. In your code, the image rotation is around its center, but when you apply the transformation to the ROI, you need to ensure it's rotated around the same center, especially when the ROI is off-centered.

When you're computing the transformation for the ROI, you're considering the ROI's coordinates in the rotated image, but not necessarily its relation to the center of the image.

To fix this:

- Compute the center of the original image.
- Compute the Affine transformation (rotation) about this center.
- Apply this transformation to the ROI's vertices.
- Plot the transformed ROI on the original image.

### Example Code

```
# ... [Rest of the code remains unchanged]

# Calculate the center of the patch (rectangle) before rotation
center_patch_x = (c0 + c1) / 2
center_patch_y = (r0 + r1) / 2

tr = mpl.transforms.Affine2D().rotate_deg_around(center_patch_x, center_patch_y, -rot_angle)
ts = axs[2].transData

rec_rot = plt.Rectangle((c0, r0), (c1 - c0), (r1 - r0), fill=False, color="w", ls="dashed", transform=tr + ts)
axs[2].add_patch(rec_rot)
axs[2].set_title("Original w/ rotated patch")

for n in range(3):
    axs[n].axis("off")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you perhaps give a bit of code? I can obtain the Affine Matrix, which has a size (2,3) (rotation + translation) I tried to apply it by a dot product, but this didn't do the case Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Edit: Added the sample code. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Dear @hkh

Unfortunately, that didn't do the trick, annoyingly. 
Do you need to transform the center_x,center_y aswell? E.g.:
Center_patch_x_rot = center_patch_x*cos(-rot_angle) - center_patch_y*sin(-rot_angle)

And the other way around for y

Or is it due to the translation not applied correctly? I.e. the translation "part" of the affine matrix is not used properly?

Answer (score 0):

So, what was missing from your answer, is that the the original image is the inverse rotation matrix from the rotated image, but you helped a lot either way! :)

Here is the modified code for anyone interested:

```
####### Everything same as before #############

# Apply rotation matrix around center of the image and crop ROI
im_rot,rot_mat = rotate_image(img,rot_angle,center=(cx,cy))
rot_mat2 = np.vstack((rot_mat,[0,0,1])) #Matplotlib requires 3x3 ([0,0,1] added as 3rd row)
inv_rot  = np.linalg.inv(rot_mat2) #Invert 3x3 rotation matrix
_, Matrix = crop_image("Crop out ROI", im_rot) #Crop ROI
c0,c1 = Matrix[0][1], Matrix[1][1] #Define vertices
r0,r1 = Matrix[0][0], Matrix[1][0] #Define vertices

#Show rotated image
axs[1].imshow(im_rot)

#Add patch on rotated image
rec = plt.Rectangle((c0, r0), c1-c0,r1-r0, fill=False, color="w", ls="dashed")
axs[1].add_patch(rec)
axs[1].set_title("Rotated and with patch")

#Show original with transformed ROI
axs[2].imshow(img)
tr = mpl.transforms.Affine2D(inv_rot) #Compute an matplotlib object, inverse matrix = inv_rot
ts = axs[2].transData

#Apply matrix with transform first by rotation, then translation w.r.t axs (ts), add patch
rec_rot = plt.Rectangle((c0, r0), c1-c0,r1-r0, fill=False, color="w", ls="dashed", transform=tr + ts)
axs[2].add_patch(rec_rot)
axs[2].set_title("Rotated with patch")
```

[The final image + rotated patch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PSEa.png)